# Can you flip a Shiny Gauge vertically?

Tags: r, shiny, gauge

I’d like to put two Shiny gauges on top of one another but then have the bottom gauge plot be flipped so that the two plots make a circle - I’ve tried Googling, but to no avail... wondering if someone has done this before and if it’s possible - I’m open to other packages, but I just really like the look of the Shiny Gauges :)

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: *"the bottom gauge plot be flipped so that the two plots make a circle"* is not understandable (at least, to me).

Comment: attached a picture of what I'm hoping to do!